# Cant seem to push and return a group of objects sequelize query

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a backend I am building with sequelize. I have a router that will make a get request. I want this get request to do a few things in a specific order.

I want the get request to get all of the records from `Members` that have the user id.
I then want to run a loop that makes a request with the `Group` table that has the id of the group with each iteration of the for loop.

Issue: I created an array and I want to push each of the returned objects from each request in the `group` into a single array `groups` and then return it after the iterations have finish with status code 200

Here is the code:

controller function:

```
getUserMember: (req, res) => {
        let groups = [];
        let user_id = req.params.userId
        Member.findAll({ where: { userId: user_id } })
            .then((response) => {
                for(let i = 0; i < response.length; i++){
                    Group.findByPk(response[i]['groupId'])
                        .then((group) => {
                            console.log(JSON.stringify(group))
                            groups.push(JSON.stringify(group))
                        })
                        .catch((err) => {
                            console.log('Getting Group by Id error: ' + JSON.stringify(err))
                        })
                }
                console.log(groups)
                res.status(200).send(data)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('Getting member by Id error: ' + JSON.stringify(err))
            })    
    },
```

logges responses:

```
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "balance", "open_tabs", "reference", "admin", "active", "DATE", "groupId", "userId" FROM "members" AS "member" WHERE "member"."userId" = '2';
[]
Getting member by Id error: {}
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "name", "description", "members", "reference", "active", "DATE", "HostId" FROM "groups" AS "group" WHERE "group"."id" = 1;
Executing (default): SELECT "id", "name", "description", "members", "reference", "active", "DATE", "HostId" FROM "groups" AS "group" WHERE "group"."id" = 3;
{"id":1,"name":"The Boys","description":null,"members":1,"reference":"32nv893f","active":true,"DATE":"2019-09-10T08:25:03.898Z","HostId":null}
{"id":3,"name":"testing2","description":"test of the homies","members":1,"reference":"scwc8s89","active":true,"DATE":"2019-09-11T06:01:40.978Z","HostId":2}
```

As you can see I am getting 2 objects back, but they are not pushing into the groups

Comment: because your `console.log(groups)` is not inside `then`

Comment: I want it it to return the groups after all of the `group` queries are completed. The return that is send is also a `[]`. it is not pushing data into the groups array that is my issue no the console.log @AyushGupta

Answer (score 0):

you can use async await for that

```
getUserMember: async (req, res) => { //<----- HERE
  let groups = [];
  let user_id = req.params.userId
  Member.findAll({
      where: {
        userId: user_id
      }
    })
    .then((response) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
          await Group.findByPk(response[i]['groupId']) //<----- HERE
          .then((group) => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(group))
            groups.push(JSON.stringify(group))
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log('Getting Group by Id error: ' + JSON.stringify(err))
          })
      }
      res.status(200).send(data)
      console.log(groups)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Getting member by Id error: ' + JSON.stringify(err))
    })
},
```